# Replacing a tabs content

Tags: android

Is there a way to replace the content of tab set in

```
public View createTabContent(String tag)
```

Or do I have to replace the Views content?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the view's content - it's safer. If you make it a FrameLayout, and store a reference to that FrameLayout during tab creation, changing the views inside becomes really straightforward.